# Does this matrix inequality hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and let $A, B,$ and $C$ be $p \times p$ symmetric positive definite matrices. ($B$ is diagonal and $C$ is tridiagonal, but hopefully this information will not be needed). I want to show that
$$a^T(A + B + C)^{-1} a \leq a^T(A + B)^{-1}a.$$

Intuitively, this makes sense to be since $C$ is positive definite, but I am not quite sure how to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that for arbitrary positive definite matrices $P,Q$, we have
$$
a^TPa \geq a^TQa \quad \forall a \implies \\
a^TP^{-1}a \leq a^TQ^{-1}a \quad \forall a
$$
Use $P \geq Q$ to mean that $a^TPa \geq a^TQa$ for all $a$.  We have
$$
P \geq Q \implies Q^{-1/2}PQ^{-1/2} \geq Q^{-1/2}QQ^{-1/2} = I
$$
Let $M = Q^{-1/2}PQ^{-1/2}$. $M \geq I$ means precisely that all eigenvalues of the (positive definite) matrix $M$ are at least $1$.  This means that all eigenvalues of the (positive definite) $M^{-1}$ are at most $1$.  We then have
$$
M^{-1} = Q^{1/2}P^{-1}Q^{1/2} \leq I \implies P^{-1} \leq Q^{-1}
$$ 
as desired.

Now, take $P = A + B + C$ and $Q = A + B$.

Comment: **Note:** We could also have used Cholesky decomposition rather than positive definite square roots.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. Is this a known result, and would it have a name? I am looking to maybe cite it.

Comment: @Greenparker no idea. If I had to look for it, I'd check on me of the Horn and Johnson books

Comment: Thanks, will try and look there.